# How to use different way to make Bootstrap button equal to same height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap version 3.3.7 How can I make the Bootstrap button to equal height columns with button at the bottom? I've found some solution is targeting the `row` or `col` class to make it same height. But can I do the same result without targeting the Bootstrap `row` and `col`? Rather than targeting the row and col class or using `position:absolute`, can I make the same result using some others CSS way? Maybe clearfix? clear:both? overflow? display:table-cell? or display: flex?

```css
/* Can I do the same result without using position:absolute? */
@media only screen and (min-width: 990px) {
button.btn.btn-success {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100px;
 left: 15px;
 margin: 20px 0;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <p>expetendis illum vidisse laboris officia sint philosophari ab laboris nescius</p>
   <div class="clearfix">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
   <p>ea pariatur laborum nulla quae sunt mandaremus laborum et pariatur legam velit adipisicing amet o admodum magna nescius noster noster</p>
   <div class="clearfix">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-4">
   <p>pariatur non varias ex ea sunt voluptatibus ingeniis summis doctrina transferrem incurreret nostrud officia proident magna do qui distinguantur fidelissimae familiaritatem lorem elit nescius enim litteris litteris iis enim cohaerescant</p>
   <div class="clearfix">
    <button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<h3>despicationes quorum quamquam aliquip coniunctione distinguantur de imitarentur 
cohaerescant e incurreret hic officia noster cupidatat arbitrantur praesentibus 
praetermissum illustriora exquisitaque ea cillum incurreret tempor vidisse minim 
e a nisi mandaremus</h3>
```

Comment: Just curious, what's the reason not to use `position:absolute` on your button? And it's a very convenient way for using with `display:table-cell`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Flexbox`. Use a custom class of yours i.e. `flex` and apply flex to `.row` and `.col-*` classes

Or you can upgrade to `bootstrap4` as its fully based on `Flexbox` and very easy to align these kinds of layout with their flex-utilities classes.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.flex .col-xs-4 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.flex .col-xs-4 p {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row flex">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p>expetendis illum vidisse laboris officia sint philosophari ab laboris nescius</p>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p>ea pariatur laborum nulla quae sunt mandaremus laborum et pariatur legam velit adipisicing amet o admodum magna nescius noster noster</p>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p>pariatur non varias ex ea sunt voluptatibus ingeniis summis doctrina transferrem incurreret nostrud officia proident magna do qui distinguantur fidelissimae familiaritatem lorem elit nescius enim litteris litteris iis enim cohaerescant</p>
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button class="btn btn-success">Button</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's really cool! What about using clear:both or display:table-cell? I think I saw some example long time ago using this method but I can't find how exactly to do it.

Comment: @Ace see `clear:both` and `display:table-cell` are both different thing...no benefit to use them together...`clear:both` is used with `floats` and using `float` make element `display:block`...I don't think it is possible with `display:table-cell` or `clear:both`....another solution can be to follow the table structure...

Comment: Alright, I got it. But I have another problem from my original answer, while I'm using CSS `position:absolute` there was a text overlay my new content. How can I fix it by using the `position:absolute` in this case? (See my updated question)

Comment: @Ace see thats the main problem with the `position:absolute` solution. you will need to control the `top` value based on the `col` content which is not a good practice...and for the temporary solution try to apply the `margin-top` to the `h3` like `margin-top:50px;`